# Conversion of a for loop into list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a for loop, that looks like this:

```
for i, item in df_olym.iterrows():
  if item.Medal != 0:
    event = item.Event
    team = item.Team
    year = item.Year
    medal = item.Medal
    df_olym['Medals_team'] = item.Medals_Won / medal_count[(event, team, year, medal)]
```

I'm having a hard time transforming this into a list comprehension, especially the 'event = items.Event' etc inserted into the if.

I started like this:

```
df_olym['Medals_team'] = [(item.Medals_Won / medal_count[(event, team, year, medal)]) for i, item in df_olym.iterrows() if item.Medal != 0, event = item.Event, team = item.Team, year = item.Year, medal = item.Medal]
```

This obviously doesn't work, I can't figure out how to insert the conditions in there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
event = item.Event
```

replace the `event` with `item.Event` in the `df_olym['Medals_team']` expression itself.

Btw why do you need a list comprehension here? Pandas can do stuff like this without any loops at all.